# Showing tables before figures while using `!ht`

Tags: floats, positioning

I am using `!ht` in both the tables and the figures.<sup>1</sup> Both the tables and the figures are large, and they take up whole pages. The problem I've faced is that the figures appear before the tables, even when that contravenes the order in the document, and even though both the tables and the figures are whole-page. For some reason, the figures just seem to take precedence. I would be sincerely grateful for any suggestions to make the tables appear first.

Thank you very much

---

<sup>1</sup> Originally `!h` but then changed: `LaTeX Warning: '!h' float specifier changed to '!ht'`.

Comment: Do you have tried `placeins` package and adding `\FloatBarrier` before the tables? If that work you might come up with an automatic solution

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to try it now.

Comment: This worked by placing `\FloatBarrier ` before the first figure following the table, rather than before the table. If you wished to post this as an answer, I would mark it accepted. In any case, thank you very much!

Comment: If a figure takes up a whole page, don't use [h] or [ht].  use [p], or at least [htp] (so that LaTeX can ignore the ht options).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it "by hand" is with `\FloatBarrier` from `placeins` package. As the name suggests it creates a barrier that floats cannot pass.
If you want to automate the process you can use `etoolbox` package. In section 2.6 explains the environment hooks that can pass a command to an environment. Since I am not really sure what code/problem you have, I left this as a recommendation.